# On binding the on() method page is attaching the events and go the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that when I try to bind the click event using JQuery on(). It doesn't go the next page.

What is your favorite color?This input is required.

```
$('#continue-bank-login-security-question-submit').off('click');
$('#continue-bank-login-security-question-submit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($('.tranfer--bank-security-question-inputs').val().length===0){
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').hide();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: is it submit button id #continue-bank-login-security-question-submit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work so that you won't remove you're original button click processing:

```
var elem = $('#continue-bank-login-security-question-submit');
var SearchButtonOnClick = elem.get(0).onclick;
elem.get(0).onclick = function() {
    var isValid = false;
    var sessionKey = '';
if ($('.tranfer--bank-security-question-inputs').val().length===0){
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').hide();
        SearchButtonOnClick();
    }   
};
```

Comment: This kind of code might work, but it's not the best way to do the job with jQuery. He should really add/remove his handlers correctly (see my answer on namespaces) and then just make sure his event propagation is correct. The code in this answer makes the assumption that there's only one other click handler and that it's on the same element. It's too brittle this way.

Comment: Chris, it jump over the next scenario without validating the error field if it is empty.

Comment: That was the great idea:)

Answer (score 2):

Because you call

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

of course it does not do anything after returning.

Comment: Is `continue-bank-login-security-question-submit` a submit button in a form?

Comment: No it is not in the form

Comment: Then why do you expect it to do *anything else*?

Comment: It is a widget like a single page application that shows different scenarios on click event. It is working for me on 3 previous pages but at this point I am stuck. If I don't remove the event handlers using off() method. It will go directly on the next scenario with out validating the input error

Comment: can you add html too?

Comment: @rizwan In that case, you can call the original event handler function directly when the validation passes.

Comment: I guess it is attaching back the removed event handlers on Jquery on() mehod?

Comment: continue-bank-login-security-question-submit is button or submit? you can also use html5 validation for this. just to add required in input type tag

Comment: Take a look to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5o93vvqz/7/. Here I call the `nextPage()` function (the original event handler) directly in onclick.

Comment: as per my understanding @meskobalazs is correct and i think returning true after next()  function will never be called

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<button id="continue-bank-login-security-question-submit" onclick="return Validate();">Next</button>

function Validate() {
    if ($('.tranfer--bank-security-question-inputs').val().length === 0) {
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').hide();
        nextPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue is solved by putting the code in the existing event handler function.     if ($('.tranfer--bank-security-question-inputs').val().length===0){
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.transfer--form-row-error').hide();
        return true;
    }